# how can i convert texture to vertex weight in blender?

Tags: modifiers, weight-painting, vertex-weights

H i , as the title say's im trying to convert a texture ( clouds or any other procedural texture ) to weight map it seems like there is a vertex weight edit modifier that could do that but i can't figure it out how can i accomplish my goal , thanks for any help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier should do the trick.

- create a vertex group "A" that is modified
- create another vertex group "B" that will have all vertices assigned. Either assign them all or set *Default Weights B* to `1` in the *Vertex Weight Mix* modifiers settings
- set *Vertex Set* to `All` and Mix Mode to `Add`, also chose a texture

This will add all weights of group B multiplied by the texture values to group A. In group A you can add/paint manually weights but you cannot remove them this way.

[image: texture mixed weights]